# PHP - Use array in mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

PHP newbie here. Here's an example of my table in a MySQL database I'm pulling data from.

```
id  classA    classB     value
------------------------------
1   A         A          1
2   A         B          5   
3   A         C          2  
4   B         A          1
5   B         B          5   
6   B         C          1  
7   C         A          8
8   C         B          5   
9   C         C          7
```

The user in puts a list of Class categories (A, B, C etc.) and my code will return the values from every combination of these pairs (e.g. [A,A], [A,B], [A,C]... etc.). I can achieve this quite easily using the following script where `$array` is the input list (e.g. [A, B, C]):

```
<?php
    // Mehtod 1 - slow
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($arr); $j++){
            $sql = "SELECT value FROM data_table WHERE '$arr[$i]'=classA AND '$arr[$j]'=classB LIMIT 1";

            $value = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            $value = mysqli_fetch_array($corr)[0];

            $results[] = array('classA' => $arr[$i], 'classB' => $arr[$j], 'value' =>  $value);
        }
    }
?>
```

However, this is quite slow because the `mysqli_query()` is inside the for loop. Instead I'd prefer to do the query in a single call. I've tried the following with no luck..

```
<?php
    // Mehtod 2 - fast
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($arr); $j++){
            // make array of class combinations
            $query_array[] = array('classA' => $arr[$i], 'classB' => $arr[$j]);
        }
    }
    // get arrays of pairs to request
    $match1 = array_column($query_array, 'classA');
    $match2 = array_column($query_array, 'classB');

    $sql = "SELECT classA, classB, value FROM data_table WHERE classA IN '$match1' AND classB IN '$match2'";

    $results = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $results = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
?>
```

Can I make a query like this with a single request? I'm a bit stuck. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want all the *possible* combinations, you do not need to build combinations inside PHP and then use them in query.

I would rather do the following:

```
SELECT classA, classB, value 
FROM data_table
WHERE classA IN ('A', 'B', 'C') AND 
      classB IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

This would consider all the combinations. It will be equivalent to:

```
SELECT classA, classB, value 
FROM data_table
WHERE (classA = 'A' AND classB = 'A') OR
      (classA = 'A' AND classB = 'B') OR
      (classA = 'A' AND classB = 'C') OR
      (classA = 'B' AND classB = 'A') OR
      (classA = 'B' AND classB = 'B') OR
      (classA = 'B' AND classB = 'C') OR
      (classA = 'C' AND classB = 'A') OR
      (classA = 'C' AND classB = 'B') OR
      (classA = 'C' AND classB = 'C')
```

In this case, the PHP code would look as follows:

```
<?php
    // Method 3 - possibly fastest and neater code

    // get comma separated values to match against
    $match_string = "('" . implode("','", $arr) . "')";

    $sql = "SELECT classA, classB, value 
             FROM data_table 
             WHERE classA IN " . $match_string . " AND 
                   classB IN " . $match_string;

    $results = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $results = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
?>
```

**Most Importantly**, to avoid against [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308) related attacks, you should rather use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks very much for this and the note on SQL injections. I had a go with your code and got it running although I needed to change `implode(",'", $arr)` to `implode("','", $arr)` (extra single quote before the comma) to make the `$match_string`.

Comment: With `json_encode($results);` I'm getting back `{"0":"A","classA":"A","1":"B","classB":"B","2":"5","corr":"5"}` where as what I'm after is `[{"classA":"A","classB":"A","value":1},{"classA":"A","classB":"B","value":5},{"classA":"B","classB":"A","value":1},{"classA":"B","classB":"B","value":5}]`

Why does it produce such a messy array?

Comment: @Lachlan.00 you will need to do some error operations. MySQL will fetch results in tabular manner only

Comment: Great, thanks @Madhur, would you kindly be able to suggest a link that details these kind of processes?

Comment: Just a note that I solved this with something like: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_NUM)){
       $array[] = $row;
   }`

Answer (score 1):

> The user in puts a list of Class categories (A, B, C etc.

- So, you are on the right track in using the IN operator, however, you can't attach `$match1` and `$match2` directly in your SQL query since they both are still arrays.
- You will have to convert them into comma separated strings and add single quote to each string, since your `classA` and `classB` are string columns in your DB table.

**Code:**

```
<?php


$match1 = array('A','B');
$match2 = array('A','B');

$match1_values = implode(",",array_map("addQuotes",$match1));
$match2_values = implode(",",array_map("addQuotes",$match2));

$sql = "SELECT classA, classB, value FROM data_table WHERE classA IN ($match1_values) AND classB IN ($match2_values)";

echo $sql;

function addQuotes($each_class_value){
    return "'".$each_class_value."'";
}
```

**Update:**

You can replace

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($arr); $j++){
            // make array of class combinations
            $query_array[] = array('classA' => $arr[$i], 'classB' => $arr[$j]);
        }
    }
    // get arrays of pairs to request
    $match1 = array_column($query_array, 'classA');
    $match2 = array_column($query_array, 'classB');
```

with

```
<?php

$match_values = implode(",",array_map("addQuotes",$arr));

$sql = "SELECT classA, classB, value FROM data_table WHERE classA IN ($match_values) AND classB IN ($match_values)";

echo $sql;

function addQuotes($each_class_value){
    return "'".$each_class_value."'";
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this!