# Dynamically creating OR conditions by passing an array to a query in MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, conditional-statements, clause

I am trying to create OR condition dynamically using an array. Given an array, of course names `$courses = array('Eng, 'Deu', 'Bio', 'Chemi')` I want to have a SQL query that uses the values of the array in its AND clause with OR conditions like:

```
    SELECT *
        FROM classe
        /* The OR conditions should be created in AND clause using array */
        WHERE class = 'EFG' AND (course = 'Eng' OR course = 'Deu' OR course = 'Bio')
```

I trying to do it in PHP MySQL.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe `and course in( 'Eng', 'Deu', 'Bio')`... should be able to generate that pretty easily with `implode`...or if using PDO this can be much easier.

Comment: @user3783243 Be very careful using `implode` on user data as that's an express train to [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of so many `OR` clauses, you can simply use [`IN(..)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

```
SELECT *
FROM classe
WHERE class = 'EFG' AND course IN ('Eng' ,'Deu', 'Bio')
```

In the PHP code, you can use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to convert the array into a comma separated string, and use it in the query string generation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, with implode I am getting a string like this: "Eng , Deu, Bio" and I want the values like this: " 'Eng' ,'Deu', 'Bio' "

Comment: @MusayyabNaveed your problem statement says that you get an array. Please confirm what exactly are you getting ?

Comment: yes it in array:  $courses = array('Rel-GK1', 'F6', 'Bio', 'Chemi');
    $placeholders = implode(', ', $courses);

Comment: @MusayyabNaveed check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53360802/2469308 You will get the idea on how to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much got it :)

Comment: @MusayyabNaveed do consider upvoting the answer as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The `IN` clause will be easier to use than `OR`s. If you are using PDO you can take advantage of its `execute` binding and build the placeholders dynamically then just pass your array to it.

```
$courses = array('Eng', 'Deu', 'Bio', 'Chemi');
$placeholders = rtrim(str_repeat('?, ', count($courses)), ', ');
$query = "select * from table WHERE class = 'EFG' AND course in ({$placeholders})";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($courses);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/jcFSv (PDO bit non functional)

Comment: If this is user data you *must* use prepared statements with placeholder values.