# how do i use in_array() function in where condition in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

**How do I use in_array() function in where condition in MYSQL?**

*It should check all key of Array*

```
$arr=array(1,2,3,4,5);  
$query="select * from tablename where id='$arr'";
```

Comment: `in_array()` doesn't exist in `mysql`. You could iterate over the array and build a `where` clause. Example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53400701/dynamically-creating-or-conditions-by-passing-an-array-to-a-query-in-mysql-php/53400798#53400798

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL uses the syntax `WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`. You can use `implode()` to convert your array to that kind of string.

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$list = implode(",", $arr);
$query = "select * FROM tablename WHERE id IN ($list)";
```

Comment: actually i have to join two table with ON condi1=condi2

Comment: That's a completely different question.

Comment: If you're trying to match an element of a comma-seprated list stored in a column, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208565/search-with-comma-separated-value-mysql/16210672#16210672

Comment: I can only answer the question you actually asked, not the question you meant to ask instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of mysql 'IN' clause. 
Step 1 : implode your array by using PHP implode function.
Step 2 : Pass that array to mysql query using IN clause.

Eg :

```
$array = array(1,2,3);
$implArray = implode(",",$array);
$query = "select * from `tablename` where `id` IN ($implArray)";
```

Above condition will work where array values are numeric.

For Alphanumeric Values, you will have to quote the values.
eg :

```
$array = array('A','B','C');
$implArray = implode("','", $array);
$query = "select * from `tablename` where `id` IN ('"'.$implArray.'"')";
```

Comment: In the string case you also need to escape special characters in the strings.

Comment: Too bad this isn't his actual question. See the comment he posted below my answer.